# Powershell ISE not recognizing changes in the script

Tags: powershell

I have been working in a script using Powershell ISE for a few months and for some reason, a weird issue started to happen today.

If I edit the script, then save and run it from the same ISE window/session, it seems the changes made has no affect. If I run the code again after close and reopen the ISE, then I see the effect of the changes.

That issue happens for every single change. I have rebooted the system and the issue still. How could it be?

Comment: when the ISE stays open ... it keeps EVERYTHING that is in the session. so - until your code overwrites the old values - your old values are there and WILL be used. [grin] the fix is to explicitly initialize everything at the start of each run OR to open a new session OR to use the `file/new-powershell-tab` menu command to open a new session inside the current ISE. new PoSh sessions in the ISE are shown by a square tab instead of the usual rounded tabs.

Comment: When you run a script within ISE, it is like dot sourcing the file.  So all the variables become global.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. I am seeing the same thing. No matter what I do changes are not picked up till after I start a new session, even if, when working on a module, I reimport module. For example, I'm writing a module to help me setup up VMs, I add an option/parameter to one of my commands `Set-VMFirmware -VM $vm -FirstBootDevice $dvdDrive` => `Set-VMFirmware -VM $vm -FirstBootDevice $dvdDrive -SecureBootTemplate MicrosoftUEFICertificateAuthority` yet the template is not changed. How would variables in session affect that? I've verified $dvdDrive and $vm are set properly

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the functions defined in the correct order in your file.

> Powershell processes in order (top-down) so the function definition
> needs to be before the function call:

```
function email($text){
    #email $text
}

#Do things
foreach{
    email($_)
}
```

The ISE keeps the functions from the last run in memory, so if you have the function call *above* the function definition, it will run the version from the previous run.

I had the same problem and stumled upon the solution while searching another topic: [Powershell script not recognizing my function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347564/powershell-script-not-recognizing-my-function)